# Access created_on from response object - get file action PODIO API

Tags: php, podio

Hello folks I'm trying to access the `created_on` object using code below but it is not working, I'm getting incorrect date `January 1, 1970 12:00`. Also tried

```
$item = PodioItem::get($item_id);
$file_id = "";
$created_on = "";
foreach ($item->files as $file) {
echo date('F j, Y h:i',strtotime($file->created_on))."<br>"; 
}
```

Below is the response object from `print_r($file,true)`, I can access the other object without any issue like `$file->file_id, $file->link`. What I'm trying to accomplish is store the created_on data in a variable then create a function to check and grab the latest date, then grab the `file_id` of it.

```
 PodioFile Object

 [__attributes:PodioObject:private] => Array
        (
            [file_id] => 464714088
            [link] => https://files.podio.com/464714088
            [perma_link] => 
            [thumbnail_link] => 
            [hosted_by] => podio
            [name] => KEjj4UQSUV.PDF
            [description] => 
            [mimetype] => application/pdf
            [size] => 785849
            [created_on] => 2017-12-08 23:03:36
            [rights] => Array
                (
                    [0] => download
                    [1] => view
                    [2] => delete
                    [3] => update
                )

 PodioFile Object
(
    [__attributes:PodioObject:private] => Array
        (
            [file_id] => 464716575
            [link] => https://files.podio.com/464716575
            [perma_link] => 
            [thumbnail_link] => 
            [hosted_by] => podio
            [name] => IiaCfJjwws.PDF
            [description] => 
            [mimetype] => application/pdf
            [size] => 785849
            [created_on] => 2017-12-08 23:15:30
            [rights] => Array
                (
                    [0] => download
                    [1] => view
                    [2] => delete
                    [3] => update
                )

PodioFile Object
(
    [__attributes:PodioObject:private] => Array
        (
            [file_id] => 464728331
            [link] => https://files.podio.com/464728331
            [perma_link] => 
            [thumbnail_link] => 
            [hosted_by] => podio
            [name] => g6cmAeUCiV.PDF
            [description] => 
            [mimetype] => application/pdf
            [size] => 785849
            [created_on] => 2017-12-08 23:49:15
            [rights] => Array
                (
                    [0] => download
                    [1] => view
                    [2] => delete
                    [3] => update
                )
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Luckily found the answer on sample provided here - https://hotexamples.com/examples/-/PodioItem/filter/php-podioitem-filter-method-examples.html

`date_format($file->created_on, 'Y/m/d H:i:s')` did the trick